# Angular PrimeNG p-calendar reactive form on patchValue error Unexpected literal at position 2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, edit, primeng-calendar

In Angular 13 application, using [PrimeNG Calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/calendar)

```
<p-calendar [minDate]="today" [showIcon]="true" styleClass="form-control" showButtonBar="true"
                                dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" inputId="icon" placeholder="dd/mm/yy"
                                formControlName="eventStartDate"></p-calendar>
```

using in a Reactive form, it is working fine while save new form.same form I am using for edit also.
To edit the form loading the data based on code.
But while `patchValue` to the form, getting the error
***ERROR Unexpected literal at position 2***
[image]

the edit code

```
loadEventToEdit() {
    this.eventService.getEventByCode(this.eventCode).subscribe((res) => {
      this.event = res;
      console.log('the event to update', this.event);

      this.theForm.patchValue(res);
```

Rest of fileds path value is working fine.

Comment: I see the date formats are different, in `eventStartDate` are you sure this is expected?

Comment: Hey Deepak, yea in DB it is storing as yy--mm-dd. also, in p-calendar I changed the format to dateFormat="yy/mm/dd", but error

Answer (score 2):

Before `patchValue` set the date as new Date.

```
loadEventToEdit() {
    this.eventService.getEventByCode(this.eventCode).subscribe((res) => {
      this.event = res;
      console.log('the event to update', this.event);

      this.event.timing.eventStartDate = new Date(
        this.event.timing.eventStartDate
      );

      this.theForm.patchValue(this.event);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give complete way to your res where res have to patched.
For FormArray you have to make getter first and the can you use **Push or insert** method to patch with form array

```
 loadEventToEdit() {
        this.eventService.getEventByCode(this.eventCode).subscribe((res) => {
          this.event = res;
         this.theForm.controls['eventStartDate'].patchValue(this.event.timing.eventStartDate);
    })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error.
Make sure having field type as Date and set it as new Date before patchValue on form.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use DayJS.

```
let dates = [
  dayjs(feature?.start_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY').toDate(),
  dayjs(feature?.end_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY').toDate(),
];

this.form.patchValue(
  {
    dateRange: dates || null
  },
  {
    emitEvent: false,
    onlySelf: true,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The P-Calendar component needs the Date object as a value, you cannot pass it to other types of objects. Therefore, when patching, be sure to access the form's controls and create it with a date object.

```
response => {
   this.yourForm.controls['likeStartDate'].patchValue(new Date(response.startDate));         }
```